# Get max user scores with min time sums

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have MySql tables that look like this

```
scores
game_id | level | score | time
--------+-------+-------+-----
1       | 1     | 1     | 10
1       | 2     | 0     | 10
1       | 3     | 1     | 20
2       | 1     | 1     | 5
2       | 2     | 1     | 15
2       | 3     | 0     | 10
3       | 1     | 0     | 10
3       | 2     | 0     | 10
3       | 3     | 0     | 10

games
game_id | user_id
--------+--------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 2
```

And i need to query it so it sums points and time per game, so it looks like this

```
game_id | user_id | sumPoints | sumTime
--------+---------+-----------+--------
1       | 1       | 2         | 40
2       | 1       | 2         | 30
3       | 2       | 0         | 30
```

And than i need to get best scores for each user (best score i mean where max(sumPoints) and min(sumTime), so it looks like this:

```
game_id | user_id | sumPoints | sumTime
--------+---------+-----------+--------
2       | 1       | 2         | 30
3       | 2       | 0         | 30
```

Thats the final result. I can do part where points and time are summing, but i have no idea how can i get tops scores per user.
I wonder, how can i do this by SQL query?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you mean `2       | 1       | 2         | 30` not `1       | 1       | 2         | 30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query below will give you the partial result.

```
SELECT  a.game_ID, 
        b.user_id,
        SUM(a.Score) sumPoint, 
        SUM(a.time) sumTime
FROM    scores a
        INNER JOIN games b
            ON a.game_ID = b.game_ID
GROUP   BY a.game_ID, b.user_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22319/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ GAME_ID ║ USER_ID ║ SUMPOINT ║ SUMTIME ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║       1 ║       1 ║        2 ║      40 ║
║       2 ║       1 ║        2 ║      30 ║
║       3 ║       2 ║        0 ║      30 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Since `MySQL` doesn't support windows functions as like any other RDBMS, this might be messy to produce your desired result.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM
        (
            SELECT  a.game_ID, 
                    b.user_id,
                    SUM(a.Score) sumPoint, 
                    SUM(a.time) sumTime
            FROM    scores a
                    INNER JOIN games b
                        ON a.game_ID = b.game_ID
            GROUP   BY a.game_ID, b.user_id
        ) a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID,
                    MIN(sumTime) sumTime
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  a.game_ID, 
                                b.user_id,
                                SUM(a.Score) sumPoint, 
                                SUM(a.time) sumTime
                        FROM    scores a
                                INNER JOIN games b
                                    ON a.game_ID = b.game_ID
                        GROUP   BY a.game_ID, b.user_id
                    ) s
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) b ON  a.user_id = b.user_id AND
                a.sumTime = b.sumTime
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22319/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ GAME_ID ║ USER_ID ║ SUMPOINT ║ SUMTIME ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║       2 ║       1 ║        2 ║      30 ║
║       3 ║       2 ║        0 ║      30 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

JW's answer is essentially the same as mine. I just think that bringing the user in so early seems to complicate things unnecessarily. How about...

```
SELECT x.*
     , u.user_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT game_id
            , SUM(score) ttl_score
            , SUM(time) ttl_time 
         FROM scores 
        GROUP 
           BY game_id
     ) x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT ttl_score
            , MIN(ttl_time) min_ttl_time
         FROM
            ( SELECT game_id
                   , SUM(score) ttl_score
                   , SUM(time) ttl_time 
                FROM scores 
               GROUP 
                  BY game_id 
            ) a
        GROUP
           BY ttl_score
     ) y
    ON y.ttl_score = x.ttl_score
   AND y.min_ttl_time = x.ttl_time
  JOIN games g
    ON g.game_id = x.game_id;
```