# Get max paired users scores with min time sums

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have MySQL tables that look like this

```
users
user_id | partner_id | name
--------+------------+-----
1       | 2          | aaa
2       | 1          | bbb
3       | 4          | ccc
4       | 3          | ddd

games
game_id | user_id
--------+--------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 2
4       | 3
5       | 4
6       | 4

scores
game_id | level | score | time
--------+-------+-------+-----
1       | 1     | 1     | 10
1       | 2     | 1     | 10
1       | 3     | 1     | 10
2       | 1     | 0     | 20
2       | 2     | 0     | 20
2       | 3     | 0     | 20
3       | 1     | 1     | 30
3       | 2     | 1     | 30
3       | 3     | 1     | 30
4       | 1     | 1     | 2
4       | 2     | 1     | 2
4       | 3     | 1     | 2
5       | 1     | 1     | 5
5       | 2     | 1     | 5
5       | 3     | 1     | 5
6       | 1     | 1     | 3
6       | 2     | 1     | 3
6       | 3     | 0     | 3
```

And i need to query it so it sums points and time per game, so it looks like this

```
game_id | user_id | sumPoints | sumTime
--------+---------+-----------+--------
1       | 1       | 3         | 30
2       | 1       | 0         | 60
3       | 2       | 3         | 90
4       | 3       | 3         | 6
5       | 4       | 3         | 15
6       | 4       | 2         | 9
```

And then i need to get best scores per pair (where it takes better score of one user), so it looks like this:

```
user1_id | user2_id | sumPoints | sumTime
---------+----------+-----------+--------
3        | 4        | 3         | 6
1        | 2        | 3         | 30
```

That's the final result. I'd really appreciate if someone could show me how it should looks like as sql query.
I'd like to mention that first part is solved by [JW 웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/jw) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328282/get-max-user-scores-with-min-time-sums)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you pair users?  Or do you mean all possible user pairs, listed with the highest score of either user?

Comment: relationship between users is shown in table users, where it shows that user with id 1 is partner with user id 2,
and because of that user with id 2 is partner with user with id 1, which shows second row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (this answers your second query)

```
SELECT 
  user_details.user_id,
  user_details.partner_id,
  score_details.score,
  score_details.time
FROM 
    ( SELECT 
        min(user_id) as user_id, 
        max(user_id) as partner_id
      FROM 
        users 
      GROUP BY
        user_id + partner_id ) AS user_details
    JOIN 
    ( SELECT 
        scores.game_id ,
        games.user_id,
        sum(score) score, 
        sum(time) time,
        @row_num := IF(@prev_value=games.user_id,@row_num+1,1) AS row_num,
        @prev_value := games.user_id
      FROM  
        scores 
        inner join games on games.game_id = scores.game_id
        inner join users on users.user_id = games.user_id
      GROUP BY
        scores.game_id
      ORDER BY
        user_id, 
        score
    ) as score_details ON ( score_details.user_id = user_details.user_id AND score_details.row_num = 1)
```

The first part of `JOIN` gets the `users` along with their `partners`, users appearing first within their pair are displayed first, eg: if there are 2 users with ID `1 and 2` I consider the `user_id` of `user` 1 as he appears first within his pair.

The second query is based on "echo_me" answer along with a `row_number` that specifies the `ranking` of the `scores` for each `user`, the highest `score` has the rank as 1 for every user.

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f3d4/10)

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select scores.game_id ,games.user_id,sum(score) score, sum(time) time
 from  scores 
 inner join games 
 on games.game_id = scores.game_id
 inner join users
 on users.user_id = games.user_id
 group by scores.game_id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcf54/3)

for the best score

```
select users.user_id as user1_id,users.partner_id as user2_id,sum(score) score, sum(time) time
from  scores 
inner join games 
on games.game_id = scores.game_id
inner join users
on users.user_id = games.user_id
group by scores.game_id
order by sum(time) asc limit 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcf54/8)

OUTPUT.

```
 USER1_ID   USER2_ID    SCORE   TIME
   1            2         3      30
```

Comment: ok, look at my edits on top,
i can't use limit because i don't know how many pairs will be